# Installing tar.gz file on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: software-installation

Completely new to coding, Linux, and Ubuntu. Attempting to install the "Stencyl" program. Downloaded the `tar.gz` file. Opened the terminal and installed `libgc-dev` (the packages for the compiler) using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libgc-dev
```

From there, I am 100% lost. How do I locate the file in my directory and install it? I have the extracted and original archived file. I'd rather look stupid and learn how to do this the right way than give up and go back to Windows.

Comment: The package tar.gz file is not an installer in the traditional sense.  The package that you downloaded is portable and only requires that the libraries it needs to be installed on the system.  The rest is as Jo-Erlend said.

Answer (score 0):

Using that file, you just right-click and extract the tar.gz (same as .zip). In the new folder, locate the file called stencyl and make sure it's marked as executable. You can do that by right-clicking it, opening preferences and looking at Permissions tab. You'll find a checkbox "Allow execution" or something like that.

Alternatively, there is a PPA (installer, updater) that you can add. The fastest and simplest to explain is to open a terminal (alt+ctrl+t) and pasting these three lines:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/games
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install stencyl
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to install package required by JRE

```
 sudo apt-get install libxtst6:i386 libXext6:i386 libxi6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libxt6:i386 libxpm4:i386 libxmu6:i386 libxp6:i386
```

cd into unzipped folder, then launch program:

```
./Stencyl
```